# How does "(\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5 " really work?

Tags: haskell, functor

In [this example from Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids), the author showed how to declare an instance of `Applicative` for function `->r`

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where  
    pure x = (\_ -> x)  
    f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

Later on, he gave a concrete example

```
ghci> (\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5  
[8.0,10.0,2.5]
```

I try to reason this snippet step by step

1. Seeing `(+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2)` as `f <*> g <*> h` and thinking that `f <*> g <*> h` returns a function `\x -> f x (g x (h x))`, I thought `(+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2)` returns a function `\x -> x+3 (x*2 (x/2))`. But I can not do `:t (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2)` in ghci, which raises this error

```
error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        a1 ~ a -> a1 -> b
      Expected type: (a -> a1 -> b) -> a1
        Actual type: a1 -> a1
    • In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘(/ 2)’
      In the expression: (+ 3) <*> (* 2) <*> (/ 2)
```

2. If `(+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2)` does return a function `\x -> x+3 (x*2 (x/2))`, how does it pattern match with the lambda function `\x y z -> [x,y,z]`? (Actually I am still having some trouble to understand lambda functions except for the really basic simple ones.)

Comment: Not sure if it's fully a dupe, as you're asking a few other things and it's a slightly more complicated example, but I hope the above link is helpful.

Comment: In the expression 3-2+1, you can't say ”I'm just going to think about the 2+1 first, which is 3, so the whole expression is 3-3, which is 0”. That's wrong because + and - have the same precedence and are left-associative in math. You're making the exact same mistake with <$> and <*> in Haskell.

Comment: Not really an answer, but here's an intuitive overview of what's going on: when you do `func <$> f <*> g <*> h <*> ... $ x`, it gets evaluated as `func (f x) (g x) (h x) ...`. It's very useful when you have some data you want to pass to all parameters of a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you got the precedence wrong. The expression

```
(\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5
```

does *not* involve as a subexpression the one you mention

```
(+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2)
```

since it should be parsed associating *to the left*, as follows:

```
((((\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3)) <*> (*2)) <*> (/2)) $ 5
```

Here, we start to simplify from the left:

```
(\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3)
= { def. <$> }
(\a y z -> [(+3) a,y,z])
```

Then, we proceed:

```
(\a y z -> [(+3) a,y,z]) <*> (*2)
= { def. <*> }
(\a z -> [(+3) a, (*2) a,z])
```

Finally,

```
(\a z -> [(+3) a, (*2) a,z]) <*> (/2)
= { def. <*> }
(\a -> [(+3) a, (*2) a, (/2) a])
```

As a last step, we let `a` to be `5`, obtaining `[5+3, 5*2, 5/2]`.

Answer (score 3):

That expression is actually parenthesized to the left:

```
(\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) <*> (/2) $ 5 
=
((((\x y z -> [x,y,z]) <$> (+3)) <*> (*2)) <*> (/2)) 5 
=
((((\x y z -> [x,y,z])  .  (+3)) <*> (*2)) <*> (/2)) 5 
=
 (((\x y z -> [x,y,z])  .  (+3)) <*> (*2)) 5   ((/2) 5)
=
  ((\x y z -> [x,y,z])  .  (+3)) 5   ((*2) 5)   ((/2) 5)
=
   (\x y z -> [x,y,z])    ((+3) 5)   ((*2) 5)   ((/2) 5)
=
   (\x y z -> [x,y,z])    (5+3)      (5*2)      (5/2)
```

which is

```
=
   let x = (5+3) in (\y z -> [x,y,z])   (5*2)      (5/2)
=
   let x = (5+3) ; y = (5*2)  in  (\z -> [x,y,z])   (5/2)
=
   let x = (5+3) ; y = (5*2) ; z = (5/2)  in   [x,y,z]
```